# How to merge different JSON files with different contents?

Tags: python, json, nosql

So I'm looking for a way to connect two JSON files together but with different headings. I'm showing the CSV file since the JSON file is a big chunk of messy data.
[orders.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6m0u.png) and [order_details.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53oft.png)

```py
print("Number of orders made on a particular day entered by a user?")
cursor.execute("""
SELECT
    COUNT (*) number_of_orders,
    o.customerID,
    o.orderDate
FROM "order" o
LEFT JOIN orderdetails od ON od.orderid = o.orderid
GROUP BY o.orderDate, o.customerID
""")
OrderDay = cursor.fetchall()
Date1 = input("Date (YYYY-MM-DD):  ")
User1 = input("UserID (5 Letters): ")
print("Number of Orders: ", end='  ')
for line in OrderDay:
    if line[2]==Date1:
        if line[1]==User1:
            print(line[0])
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

This is how it would look like if I'm using Python with SQL. Since I'm doing Python with NoSQL now, I have to merge the JSON files before putting it in a collection. But if anyone knows how I can merge collections to create new collections let me know too.

Comment: The images you linked are identical it seems.

Comment: @Timbolt ok just edited